# Динамическая переменная в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли на jquery реализовать динамическую переменную подобно angular js? Т.е. при изменении этой переменной она сразу выводится, например у меня есть некоторый плагин, там эта переменная меняется, как мне ее вывести вне плагина при условии что она изменилась? 
Сам плагин: В нем меняется переменная, которая задается в параметре инициализации плагина - varName. Идея в том, чтобы человек мог просто создать переменные, а потом обычным арифметическим выражением их сложить / умножить и тд.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    Counter: function(options) {
      this.defaults = {
        SliderMin: 1,
        SliderMax: 50,
        SliderValue: 4,
        varName: 'varSliderValue'
      };
      var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
      return this.each(function() {
        var CounterWrapper = this;
        // Флаг начала отсчета
        var counterInc = false;
        var counterDec = false;
        var slider = $(".ui-widget-content", CounterWrapper);
        $(".ui-widget-content", CounterWrapper).slider({
          range: "min",
          value: settings.SliderValue,
          min: settings.SliderMin,
          max: settings.SliderMax,
          slide: function(event, ui) {
            $(".counter", CounterWrapper).val(ui.value).trigger("change");
          }
        });
        window[settings.varName] = slider.slider("value");
        $(".counter", CounterWrapper).val(slider.slider("value"));
        $(".counter", CounterWrapper).on("keyup", function() {
          slider.slider("option", "value", $(".counter", CounterWrapper).val());
        })


        // Счетчик
        var counter = slider.slider("value");
        var idproc

        // Зажата клавиша мыши
        $(".inc", CounterWrapper).mousedown(function() {
          counterInc = true;
          counter = slider.slider("value")
          idproc = setInterval(calculation, 50)
        });
        $(".dec", CounterWrapper).mousedown(function() {
          counterDec = true;
          counter = slider.slider("value")
          idproc = setInterval(calculation, 50)
        });

        // Отпущена клавиша мыши
        $(".inc", CounterWrapper).mouseup(function() {
          counterInc = false;
        }).mouseleave(function() {
          counterInc = false;
        });
        $(".dec", CounterWrapper).mouseup(function() {
          counterDec = false;
        }).mouseleave(function() {
          counterDec = false;
        });
        // Подсчет секунд
        function calculation() {
          if (counterInc && counter != settings.SliderMax) {
            $(".counter", CounterWrapper).val(++counter);
            slider.slider("option", "value", counter).val();
          } else if (counterDec && counter != settings.SliderMin) {
            $(".counter", CounterWrapper).val(--counter);
            slider.slider("option", "value", counter).val();
          } else {
            clearInterval(idproc);
          }
        }

      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
$('#children-slider').Counter({
  SliderMax: 100
});
$('.var').html(varSliderValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<div id="children-slider">
  <div class="ui-widget-content"></div>
  <button class="inc">Увеличить</button>
  <input type="text" class="counter">
  <button class="dec">Уменьшить</button>
</div>
<div>та самая переменная: <span class="var"></span></div>
```

Comment: нужно бы больше данных что за плагин и что смотрите.... по идее можно открыть паттерн "наблюдатель (observer)"  и сделать его)

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил подробное объяснение и сам плагин

Answer (score 1):

Не самое логичное решение, но все-же, использовать trigger change на изменении input куда вводится переменная:

```
$(sliderInput).on('keyup change', function () {
                window[settings.varName] = $(sliderInput).val();
                recount ();
});
```

```js
(function ($) {
 $.fn.extend({
  Counter: function (options) {
   this.defaults = {
    SliderMin: 1,
    SliderMax: 50,
    SliderValue: 4,
    varName: "varSliderValue"
   };
   var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
   return this.each(function () {
    var CounterWrapper = this;
    // Флаг начала отсчета
    var counterInc = false;
    var counterDec = false;
    var slider = $(".ui-widget-content", CounterWrapper);
    var sliderInput = $(".counter", CounterWrapper);
    slider.slider({
     range: "min",
     value: settings.SliderValue,
     min: settings.SliderMin,
     max: settings.SliderMax,
     slide: function (event, ui) {
      sliderInput.val(ui.value).trigger("change");
     }
    });
    sliderInput.val(slider.slider("value"));
    sliderInput.on("keyup", function () {
     slider.slider( "option", "value", sliderInput.val());
    })
    // Счетчик
    var counter = slider.slider("value");
    var idproc

    // Зажата клавиша мыши
    $(".inc", CounterWrapper).mousedown(function () {
     counterInc = true;
     counter = slider.slider("value")
     idproc = setInterval(calculation, 50)
    });
    $(".dec", CounterWrapper).mousedown(function () {
     counterDec = true;
     counter = slider.slider("value")
     idproc = setInterval(calculation, 50)
    });

    // Отпущена клавиша мыши
    $(".inc", CounterWrapper).mouseup(function () {
     counterInc = false;
    }).mouseleave(function () {
     counterInc = false;
    });
    $(".dec", CounterWrapper).mouseup(function () {
     counterDec = false;
    }).mouseleave(function () {
     counterDec = false;
    });
    // Подсчет секунд
    function calculation() {
     if (counterInc && counter != settings.SliderMax) {
      sliderInput.val(++counter).trigger("change");
      slider.slider( "option", "value", counter).val();
     } else if (counterDec && counter != settings.SliderMin) {
      sliderInput.val(--counter).trigger("change");;
      slider.slider( "option", "value", counter).val();
     } else {
      clearInterval(idproc);
     }
    }
    $(sliderInput).on('keyup change', function () {
     window[settings.varName] = $(sliderInput).val();
     recount ();
    });
   });
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
$('#children-slider').Counter({
 SliderMax: 100,
 varName: "newVar"
});
function recount () {
 $('.var').html(newVar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<div id="children-slider">
  <div class="ui-widget-content"></div>
  <button class="inc">Увеличить</button>
  <input type="text" class="counter">
  <button class="dec">Уменьшить</button>
</div>
<div>та самая переменная: <span class="var"></span></div>
```